# Connecting two dockerized kafka clusters

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

How connect two kafka clusters on different VM's together ?

On my **Windows maschine** with the IP-Address: **192.168.2.22**
i downloaded docker-compose.yml from https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-single.yml and started it in a cmd-console with `docker-compose up -d`

**Create Topic:**

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --create --topic my-Windows-Topic-1
```

**Check access to Topic:** in different ways (but in the same cmd-console)

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --list
```

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:19092 --list
```

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --list
```

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.22:9092  --list
```

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.22:29092 --list
```

```
docker run --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka bash -c "kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.22:9092  --list"
```

```
docker run --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka bash -c "kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.22:29092 --list"
```

all the above commands show the same output so far

> > my-Windows-Topic-1

---

Now i change to a **Linux-Virtual-Maschine** with IP: **192.168.94.130**

and again

**Check access** to the Windows **Topic:**

```
docker run --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka bash -c "kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.22:9092 --list"
```

> > my-Windows-Topic-1

So far everything is fine. I have access to the topic from internal and external!

---

(Still from the Linux console)
Now i'm creating a second independent cluster in the same way as above:

downloaded https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-single.yml and started with `docker-compose up -d`

**Create** Linux **Topic:**

```
docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic my-Linux-Topic
```

**Check Topic:**

```
$ docker exec kafka1 kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --list
my-Linux-Topic
```

---

How to configure both clusters to display both outputs?

```
my-Windows-Topic-1
```

and

```
my-Linux-Topic
```

at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard-time following the question, but if you want multiple brokers, then the repo you've linked to already has an example of that (in one Kafka cluster)

If you have multiple compose files, then they will not share a Docker network, by default, and so will be unable to reach each other.

If you want to connect them, then [use a bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> configure both clusters to display both output ... at the same time?

You can't; you can only list topics of one cluster at a time.

You could use Conduktor *Platform* to run a UI where you can link both clusters to it, then display topics there, without using any terminal commands.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Kafka. I would like to have a cluster of multiple computers to provide failover.
Maybe what I'm looking for is called a "multi region" cluster ?
If such a thing is possible is there compose files as an example ?

Comment: If you're using one computer, with windows terminal (Docker Desktop) and WSL2 on the same machine, running Docker in Linux Hypervisor... That's one host, one disk, one "region". If you want to run a distributed Kafka cluster, and are new to it, then I personally suggest not using Docker, rather a hosted solution such as Upstash, Amazon MSK, Confluent Cloud, etc. Otherwise, Docker Compose is primarily meant to run on one machine, anyway. Docker Swarm or Kubernetes run containers across "regions", but only after you setup all networking and hosts to install said software

Comment: You can run multiple containers on one host/VM for "fail over" of the individual containers, but if that machine dies, then obviously that's not fault tolerant. Not clear from the question where your VMs are running, but I assume it's only one host.